# Rank of tensor product of morphisms

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative, noetherian, unital ring, $F$ and $G$ two projective $R$ modules, $\phi: F\to G$ a module morphism and $M$ a finitely generated $R$ module such that $$\phi \otimes M := \phi \otimes id_M \neq 0.$$
We define the rank of $\phi$ on $M$ (denoted as $\operatorname{rank}(\phi,M)$ ) as the largest $k\in \mathbb N$, such that $$\Lambda^k( \phi \otimes M ) \neq 0, \Lambda^{k+1}( \phi \otimes M ) = 0,$$ where $\Lambda^k$ denotes the $k$-th exterior power. I'm trying to understand this concept of rank.

I have already proven that this definition coincides with the usual rank concept if $F$ and $G$ are two free $R$ modules. 
My question concerns the following setup:

Let $F$ and $G$ be free and let $\phi$ be a monomorphism, then $\operatorname{rank}(\phi,M)\leq \operatorname{rank}(F)$. The statement is clear if we would look at $\operatorname{rank}(\phi)$. But I'm having trouble understanding it for $\phi \otimes M$.

**edit:** I just saw that we additionally assume that $\phi \otimes M$ is a monomorphism.